# Passed function as prop and is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to passed function toggle and is undefined. How to fix that ?

```
 function page() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

     const handleToggle = () => {
     setOpen(!open);
      };

   return (
     <div>
      <Sidebar state={open} callback={handleToggle} />
      </div>
   );
 }

 export default page;
```

//Passing to Sidebar component //

```
const Sidebar = ({callback,state}:any) => {
 }
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Are `Sidebar` and `page` located in the same file?

Comment: @VincentLa no, Sidebar is in completely different file

Comment: Is the Sidebar function marked as an `export`?

Comment: Please reproduce a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-cherry-6vihwy) with your code, and so we can see what went wrong with it.

Comment: Please share a github repo for the while project.... we can debug better!

Answer (score 1):

I would consider just passing props on the header of Sidebar component (something like):

```
const Sidebar = (props) => {...}
```

Then you can access props.callback and props.state inside your code.
Another piece of advice I could give you is to not use the state itself to change on the handler, but use the previous snapshot, for example:

```
const handleToggle = () => {
 setOpen(prevIsOpen => !prevIsOpen);
};
```

This way you could avoid some random bugs. (See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Don't know if this was of any help but hope it was (not a lot of experience in React).

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. Unfortunately this did not work ..I dont know why function doesn't work when I'm passing as function prop from parent to child but when I'm moving state and function to a child then everything works ...

Comment: I tried to build a program that simulates yours and I didn't have any problem passing the function as prop. Would you pass the error code to take a look?
If it is of any help I found this other Stack post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948416/react-function-passed-in-props-is-undefined

Comment: Thank u Jonathan for your help ! :) . Unfortunately, I dont have any errors on console . Thats the strange one. ..